find div in repeater when onclick
My friends, I want to change the class of a tag div in on click button (asp.net), but that div is inside the repeater, how can I find it? and change class?
Actually, I want to change bootstrap column class.
I hope I have expressed the meaning well, thank you all.

can you please post some code? are you using onClick (server) or onClientClick (client) ?

Sure, assuming this markup:
        <style>
            .myhighlight {
                background-color:lightblue;
                font:bold;
            }

        </style>


        <h3>Hotels</h3>
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">

            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hPK" runat="server"
                    Value='<%# Eval("ID") %>'
                    />
                <div id="mystylediv" runat="server">

                    <div style="float: left; width: 30%">

                        <asp:Label ID="lblHotelName" runat="server"
                            Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>'
                            Font-Size="X-Large">
                        </asp:Label>
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server"
                            Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>'>
                        </asp:Label>

                    </div>
                    <div style="float: left">
                        <asp:Button ID="cmdSel" runat="server"
                            Text="Select"
                            CssClass="btn"
                            OnClick="cmdSel_Click" />
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear: both">
                    </div>
                    <hr />

                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:Repeater>

So, for the one row button click, then we have this code:
Protected Sub cmdSel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim btn As Button = sender
    Dim rRow As RepeaterItem = btn.NamingContainer

    Dim hPK As HiddenField = rRow.FindControl("hPK")
    Dim intPK As Integer = hPK.Value

    Session("RowPK") = intPK    ' save row selected database PK for later

    Dim MyDiv As HtmlControl = rRow.FindControl("mystylediv")
    MyDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "myhighlight")

End Sub

So, when the page loads and the click the button for that row, we have this:

So, on a button (that resides in the repeater row), then clicking on that button, the code behind shows how to grab the one row, and thus controls such as a "div" or any text box, or label etc. can then be had by using FindControl to get use of controls for that one given row.
At that point, you are free to add .background colors, or even add a class attribute for any style class you want, be it a Bootstrap one, or any custom style class you choose.
Edit: Use client side code
While this question is to change css, and hence the follow up in comments is asking how to do this client side, which of course makes the most sense.
Keep in mind the above server side code example is still often required, and use of the NamingContainer property to get the current row on a button click for server side code is often used.
However, for changing some css? Yes, client side code is the preferred approach here.
Keep in mind that the HTML standard is to not allow nor have multiple controls on a given page with the same control id. So, asp.net will generate a new control id for each row of the repeater. Of course, this assumes that such controls have runat="server".
So, you find controls have a generated new name for each row, usually based on the RepeaterName_ControlName_RowIndex.
So, in most cases, you can just use the .parent() method of jQuery to move up to the parent div.
And often one will want use of controls for that given row, and hence the following client side code shows how we can use .parent() to grab the housing div, and also shows how to grab one control from that given row.
Hence, our button in the repeater becomes this:
                    <div style="float: left">
                        <asp:Button ID="cmdSel" runat="server"
                            Text="Select"
                            CssClass="btn"
                            OnClientClick="changeblue(this);return false" />
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear: both">

And our script code after the repeater is this:
        <script>

            function changeblue(btn) {

                var mybtn = $(btn)
                var sTbox = "#" + mybtn.attr("id").replace("cmdSel", "lblDescription")
                console.log($(sTbox).text())  // get description text for this row

                var MyDiv = $(btn).parent().parent()
                MyDiv.addClass("myhighlight")

            }


        </script>

So, the effect and coloring of the one row produces the same result as the server-side code, but occurs client-side without a post-back.

Quite instructive answer as always. Can you please also consider a client-side approach? Because tasks like changing html attributes and properties do not require server-side process.

Sure, see my edit, I added a client side example. (I used jQuery).

Thanks for your kind response and comprehensive answer Mr. Kallal.
